# Python If always wrong

Tags: python, if-statement

I don't know why but when answering correctly, it always says it's not equal to the answers.

```
import random
a = random.randint(1,100)
b = random.randint(1,100)
answer = a + b
print(answer)
print(f"{a} + {b}")
urAnswer = input("Answer : ")
print("Your answer = " + urAnswer)
if urAnswer == answer:
  print("You're Correct!")
else:
  print(f"You answered {urAnswer}. Which wasn't the correct answer! The Correct Answer was {answer}")
```

Comment: `urAnswer` is a `str` object, which will never equal an `int` object like `answer`

Comment: Thanks! I need to use int() then.

Comment: If you're following a tutorial, it might be worth checking which version of Python it is expecting. You're using 3 (which is good, it's what you should be using), but in Python2, `input('prompt: ')` would return an `int` if you entered `3` at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

The inputs supplied via  input is of type string, Need to convert the input to int. Also you can do a validation for the input.

```
a = random.randint(1,100)
b = random.randint(1,100)
answer = a + b
print(answer)
print(f"{a} + {b}")
urAnswer = input("Answer : ")
print("Your answer = " + urAnswer)
if int(urAnswer) == answer:
  print("You're Correct!")
else:
  print(f"You answered {urAnswer}. Which wasn't the correct answer! The Correct Answer was {answer}")
```

Answer (score -1):

You are comparing a string to an integer.
Make the answer an integer before comparing so the script will work

if int(urAnswer) == answer: